# Negating (\not) a stackrel expression

Tags: stacking-symbols

I am using the following command to generate an arrow with a superscript, which is then negated:

```
\not \stackrel{x}{\Longrightarrow}
```

The problem is that the "\not" slash appears far to the left on the arrow. It also slashes through the arrow but is not long enough to slash through the superscript.

What's the right way to fix these issues?

Comment: Did you try the `centernot` package?

Comment: That definitely handles the centering issue, but not the slash length. Thanks! (Make that an answer?)

Comment: There's `cancel` that might be good for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,relsize}

\newcommand\vrel[1]{\overset{#1}{\Longrightarrow}}
\newcommand{\negvrel}[1]{\mathrel{%
  \ooalign{%
    \hidewidth\raisebox{.4ex}{$\mathlarger{\mathlarger{/}}$}\hidewidth\cr
    $\vrel{#1}$\cr
  }%
}}

\begin{document}

$A \vrel{x} B \negvrel{x} C$

\end{document}
```

[image]